# Wordpress - Only show tags under the current Category

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Looking into showing tags on the Archieve.php file in Wordpress to only show tags that are under the current Category.

At the moment all I have been able to do is show all the tags instead of pick the ones under just the current category with the code below:

```
<ul id="blog-tags">
<?php
$tags = get_tags();
if ( $tags ) {
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<li>';

    if ( (int) $tag->term_id === get_queried_object_id() )
        echo "<b>$tag->name</b>";
    else
        printf(
            '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
            get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ),
            $tag->name
        );

    echo '</li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to manipulate my code above to do what I want? Or have I got to take a completely different approach.

Comment: Do you have two accounts here? Didn't you post this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148089/how-do-you-set-a-active-tag-in-wordpress-that-matches-the-post-your-on ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly sure this is what you want but basically just need to loop through all posts by category, then grab the tags for those posts.

You could try something like this to get all the tags for the current category. You would need to manipulate it a bit to spit it out formatted the way you want with certain `HTML` .

```
<?php
$custom_query = new WP_Query( 
array( 
    'cat' => get_query_var('cat') 
  ) 
);
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
    }
endwhile;
endif;

$tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags);
$tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);

$args = array(
'smallest'  => 12,
'largest'   => 12,
'unit'      => 'px',
'number'    => 0,
'format'    => 'list',
'include'   => $tags_str
);
wp_tag_cloud($args);
// or use  <?php $my_tags = wp_tag_cloud( 'format=array' ); ?> to have them in an array that you can format after
?>
```

Comment: I suggest to declare `$all_tags` array as `NULL` before `if`, and check `!is_null($all_tags)` after `endif` to prevent PHP errors.